# Reading objects from a priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I've a priority queue in which I've put several objects. These objects are from a class **Prod** that has the following fields:

```
int Id;
String Gtin;
String Msg;
```

so my queue looks like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Prod> pq= new PriorityQueue<Prod>();
pq.add(new Prod(1,"454545","Counter"));
pq.add(new Prod(1,"676767","Counter"));
pq.add(new Prod(1,"787878","Counter"));
pq.add(new Prod(2,"232323","FLoor"));
pq.add(new Prod(2,"323232","Floor"));
pq.add(new Prod(2,"989898","Floor"));
```

I am then using the iterator to fetch the elements

```
Iterator iterator = pq.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
Object prod= iterator.next();
System.out.println("Prod:"+ prod);
}
```

However, I need to fetch all the Gtins belonging to Id 1 and put them into a file i.e. "454545","676767","787878" for Id 1 needs to be extracted in this example and the same should be repeated for all other Ids. I don't know how to do this. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Adding elements to `PriorityQueue` is incorrect. 2. Where you are facing the problem.

Comment: `Prod` must implement `Comparable<Prod>` to be used with a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). What is the [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of `Prod`?

Comment: the items in the queue are sorted based on the Ids which is the natural sorting and the `Prod` has implemented the `Comparable<Prod>` interface:     @Override
    public int compareTo(Prod prod) {
        return this.ID.compareTo(prod.ID);
   }
}

Comment: @laune There is no evidence anywhere that writing the file (singular) is the problem.

Comment: @EJP I did suggest the sort. OP didn't say clearly where the problem lies. Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: @laune You suggested (a) a redundant sort and (b) a non-existent problem writing files. See the duplicated question for the real answer.

Comment: @EJP So why is the sort by Id redundant while the priority queue is not sorted? How would you group the collection by id values? Please enlighten me!

Comment: @laune See my answer in the duplicated question. I'm not going to repeat it all here like a parrot. The `Comparator` does the grouping, as the OP himself has already pointed out.

Comment: But removing the entries from the queue, one by one, will destroy the queue - and you don't know that this is OK, do you? The javadoc suggests the sort, as has been pointed out elsewhere. At least, sorting is a plausible alternative to iterated removal.

Comment: @laune That is the intended usage of a `PriorityQueue` and indeed of any queue: you put things into it and you take them out again.

Comment: @EJP Quite so, but when I answered with the sort, it wasn't even clear what the ordering principle of the queue was in the first place. Note that OP supplied this info only later. I didn't see that until long after...